# Is it enough to show function tends to rational to show integral convergence?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Suppose I had $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{4x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x + 1}$. We know that as $x \to \infty$, $\frac{4x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x + 1}$ ~ $\frac{4x^2}{x^3} = 4/x$

So we know it will diverge by the p-test.

But is this a valid reasoning? [Do we need to show the ~ relation?

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic it is. However, in general it's not too hard to make it rigorous. Observe when $x\geq 1$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{4x^2}{x^3+x^2+x+1} \geq \frac{4x^2}{(1+x)^3} 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_1 \frac{4x^2}{(1+x)^3}\ dx \leq \int^\infty_1 \frac{4x^2}{1+x+x^2+x^3}\ dx.
\end{align}
The left-hand side integral can be easily computed since
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^3} = \frac{(x+1-1)^2}{(1+x)^3} = \frac{(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+1}{(1+x)^3} = \frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{2}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}
\end{align}
which are all easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence  test is valid only for functions of which the signum, at least near the point where you study the convergence, doesn't change.

for example,

$\int^{+\infty } ln(1+\frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}})dx$ diverges but

$\int^{+\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$
converges,

even if there is equivalence.
( the signum is changing).